# How to connect Informix to SQL Server as a linked server?

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, informix

We got to the point that we can see the tables, but we can't see the columns.  For the record, all of the tables are called "root.".  I don't know what that means in Informix speak.  Based on the table names I think they are the tables that we want to see, but I'm not sure that they aren't all system tables.

FWIW, the error I see from SQL Server is:  "Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "CMS".  (Microsoft SQL Server, Error 7303)"

It doesn't seem very helpful.

Comment: Normally, the tables in an Informix database are not called `root`; indeed, unless you do your DBA work as user `root` on a Unix-like system, the owner of the tables won't be `root` either. Is the Informix server running on a Windows system or a Unix system? Can you connect to the Informix server from the Windows system where the SQL Server is running? If you don't have basic connectivity working (maybe you need to use Informix's SETNET32 program to configure your connection), then it's likely that you can't connect as a linked server either.

Comment: I'm not sure that if you can connect separately then you will automatically be able to connect as a linked server — there may be other work to do.  (I'm no expert on Windows, in case you haven't guessed.)

Comment: I think that if the tables are all called (owned by) root, it's a fair guess that the db is on *nix! Otherwise they'd be called Admin! :-)

Comment: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21195578